# How to connect to multiple SMSC IP

Tags: node.js, sms-gateway

I have a 4 SMSC IP and I connect them randomly. Is there a way to connect to the 2nd, 3rd or 4th if the first SMSC IP failed?

Here's my current code.

```
const smsc = [
  '192.168.1.1',
  '192.168.1.2',
  '192.168.1.3',
  '192.168.1.4',
];
const port = 1234
  
//iterate SMSC IP
var smsc_ip = smsc[Math.floor(Math.random() * smsc.length)];

var session = new smpp.Session({host: smsc_ip, port: port});
var didConnect = false;
session.on('connect', function(){
    didConnect = true;
    session.bind_transceiver({
            system_id: 'system_id',
            password: 'password',
            system_type: "SENDER",
            interface_version: 1,
    }, function(pdu) {
        console.log('pdu status', lookupPDUStatusKey(pdu.command_status));
        if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
            console.log('Successfully bound')
        }
    });
});



session.on('close', function(){
    console.log('smpp disconnected')
    if (didConnect) {
        connectSMPP();
    }
});

session.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('smpp error', error)
    didConnect = false;
});


function connectSMPP () {
    // connect to another SMSC IP?
    console.log('smpp reconnecting');
    session.connect();
}

function lookupPDUStatusKey(pduCommandStatus) {
    for (var k in smpp.errors) {
      if (smpp.errors[k] == pduCommandStatus) {
        return k
      }
    }
  }
```

I have a connectSMPP function to reconnect the session if it the session was disconnected. Should I also include a new session inside the connectSMPP to initialize a new session and using all the rest of the SMSC IP then exit if all of the SMSC IP is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your active sessions into main list, then add an enquire link function outside the main thread to check connection health. You can use scheduling by 10 seconds interval, and if the enquire link failed to connect, remove it from main list and add it to reconnect list, which in reconnect list you can perform reconnect method.